# Pass variable in a table PHP to a bootstrap modal

Tags: php

I'm just wondering on how to  pass a variable in a modal in php I need to show a modal wherein the user can edit the selected row but I'm having a trouble in passing the variables of the selected row into the modal.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM techsupport,techdetails WHERE techsupport.id = techdetails.id");

while ($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $ids = $fetch['id'];
    $serv_code = $fetch['service_code'];
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><a href='#' data-target='#editModal$ids' data-toggle='modal' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['service_code']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['log_date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['title']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['remarks']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['status']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['parts']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['request_date']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$fetch['received_date']."</td>";
}

?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>         
</div>
```

And here's for the Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal<?php echo $ids;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Modal only shows when I click the last Record.

Comment: 1/ Where do you build the modal? 2/ Where is the begin of your HTML? (you close some div + table but can't find where it begins?

Comment: Are your modals done in a loop? Is `$ids` set correctly in that loop? View the source or inspect element in your browser and make sure every modal has a unique `id`. (`id="editModal<?php echo $ids;?>"`)

Comment: its inside the body tag

Comment: no the modal is not in the loop

Comment: the last record only is getting display in the modal

Comment: You'd either need code _for every modal_ you want to open or read up on how to load modal content dynamically. As of now, you generate let's say 10 links, but only one modal with `id="editModal<?php echo $ids;?>"`. Since you don't update `$ids` anywhere it takes the last value you set it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your modal html code is out of while statement.

I am not sure but You may try like below..

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM techsupport,techdetails WHERE techsupport.id = techdetails.id");

while ($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$ids = $fetch['id'];
$serv_code = $fetch['service_code'];
?>
<tr>
<td><a href='#' data-target='#editModal<?php echo $ids;?>' data-toggle='modal' ><i class='fa fa-edit'></i></a></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['id'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['service_code'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['log_date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['title'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['remarks'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['status'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['parts'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['request_date'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fetch['received_date'];?>
    <!-- Hidden Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="editModal<?php echo $ids;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    <!--Ends Hidden Modal -->
 </td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>


        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```